# search a string which contains "/" and replace using sed

Tags: sed

How to search a pattern and remove the line using sed which contains special characters like "ranasnfs2:/SA_kits/prod"

I tried using a variable to hold the complete string and then recall the variable in sed command but it is not working.

```
echo $a
ranasnfs2:/SA_kits/prod
    sed -i '/"$a"/d' test.txt
    cat test.txt | grep -i SA
/SA_kits        -rw,suid,soft,retry=4   ranasnfs2:/SA_kits/prod
```

Comment: Which sed are you using? GNU? Can you identify a character which is guaranteed not to occur in the string to search for? E.g. "%".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escape a string for a sed replace pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern)

Comment: Switch from `s///` to `s|||`, e.g.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the slash character.
Use this for deleting lines which contain a `/`:

`sed '/\//d' file`